# How do I reorder dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 long lists of dictionaries. The format of the lists are like the following ones:

```
myList1 = [{'id':1, 'bar':14},
           {'id':2, 'car':641},
           {'id':3, 'tar':84},
           {'id':12, 'bar':14},
           {'id':52, 'car':641},
           {'id':6, 'tar':84}]


myList2 = [{'id':12, 'bar':14},
           {'id':2, 'car':641},
           {'id':3, 'tar':84},
           {'id':1, 'bar':14},
           {'id':52, 'car':641},
           {'id':6, 'tar':84}]
```

I want the last 1000 dictionaries in both lists to be the same (same 'id'). Any suggestions?

I tried to print one list's last 1000 dictionaries and then change the other list one dictionary by one dictionary. However, that is too time consuming...

Comment: Why?  It's not the right data structure for that data.  You should have a dictionary where the key is `id` and the other data is the value.

Comment: Why are you retaining two identical copies of your data?

Comment: Is there anything in particular about the order of the second list that you want to preserve, or do you just want both lists to have the same order?

Comment: Wait, wait... you want only the last 1000 dictionaries to be the same? Why?

Comment: I want the last dictionaries in both lists to be the same. For example,  the last 3 elements of both of the lists to be id: 1, id 52, id:6. The examples are toy examples, I have two lists which are longer than 3000.  I want the last 1000 dictionaries in both lists to be the same

Comment: Your question isn't posed well. Are the last 1000 dictionaries all exactly the same in both lists, only their order is different, or are some of the last 1000 dictionaries in the first list scattered around in the second list? Can you not just take the last 1000 of whichever one you want as a slice and reassign that same slice in the first? It's honestly really confusing why you want to do this.

Comment: Since the last 1000 will be used for a further split. I have used list1 to do the splitting. List2 is my new data. I hope to keep consistent of the splited data and add new data. So I want the last 1000 in both lists to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList1 = [{'id':1, 'bar':14},
           {'id':2, 'car':641},
           {'id':3, 'tar':84},
           {'id':12, 'bar':14},
           {'id':52, 'car':641},
           {'id':6, 'tar':84}]


myList2 = [{'id':12, 'bar':14},
           {'id':2, 'car':641},
           {'id':3, 'tar':84},
           {'id':1, 'bar':14},
           {'id':52, 'car':641},
           {'id':6, 'tar':84}]

mySortedList1 = sorted(myList1, key=lambda item: item["id"])
mySortedList2 = sorted(myList2, key=lambda item: item["id"])

# check that it works
from itertools import islice
start1 = max(0, len(mySortedList1)-1000)
start2 = max(0, len(mySortedList2)-1000)
assert myList1[start1:] == myList2[start2:]
```

It does not work with your example data because you have less than 1000 last elements in common.